# How to display a dataframe while changing one of its column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's take this dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Col1=['a','b','c'], Col2=[1,-3,2]))
  Col1  Col2
0    a     1
1    b    -3
2    c     2
```

I would like to display this dataframe while changing Col2, replacing negative numbers by "neg" and positive ones by "pos".
I could modify the column / add a new column then display or create a new dataframe specially to display that but I wonder if there is a more optimal way to do as **I don't want to keep this modification**.

I tried the following but I get the error "lambda cannot contain assignment" :

```
df.apply(lambda x : x['Col2'] = "pos" if x['Col2'] >= 0 else "neg")
```

Is there please a way to do ?

Comment: `df['Col2'] = np.where(df['Col2'] >= 0 ,'pos','neg')` you dont need apply for this actually , to just display and not modify use same with assign which returns a copy : `df.assign(Col2=np.where(df['Col2'] >= 0 ,'pos','neg'))`

Comment: Do not delete the question!  That defeats the purpose of Stack Overflow!

Comment: I had closed it as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column , not sure why was this reopened

Comment: I don't see why it is duplicate of this ? There is no df.assign in this post

Comment: i see what you mean , i was more focussed on the code not working part of it. I will post an answer

Comment: I wrote one, do you want I delete it in order to you wrote yours ?

Comment: @Ewdlam thats fine  as long as the question is answered :)

Comment: Fine, I just didn't want to steal your up votes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In agreement with @anky_91 comment, the solution is using [df.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) :

```
df.assign(Col2=np.where(df['Col2'] >= 0 ,'pos','neg'))
```

Output :

```
  Col1 Col2
0    a  pos
1    b  neg
2    c  pos
```